# Best way to use activerecord to look for ID number in JSON encoded string

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I am storing JSON strings of ID numbers in my database for some website settings. I need create an active record query to look for an ID number in this string. What's the best way to do this?

Example of stored string:

```
["25","26","27","28","29"]
```

I was thinking perhaps:

```
$this->db->like('settings', '"28"');
```

However, this seems a little improvised...

Comment: I have a feeling you are doing something wrong and ineffective. Looks like you do some associations, storing many associations in 1 row? If so, why don't you just use 1 row for 1 association, and there you will be able to construct a query.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are searching for something like:

```
$this->db->where_in('id', json_decode('["25","26","27","28","29"]'));
```

Comment: I need to match a single ID number. So I only have a value like '28' to check against the column contents.